# how can i efficiently query on a Cassandra table having various counts to retrieve?

Tags: cassandra

I have a Cassandra Table FeedCount with Partition key (PKey) cluster keys (filetype,status, time).
I need to get data for a chart where i need to show

- TOTAL COUNT: 100
- PASSED : 80
- FAILED : 20

how shall i query efficiently on above table.

1. Query for COUNT ALL for Total as  count(*) &  Passed as: Count(*)
       where status ="passed" and then programmatically calculate failed as
       Failed = Total - passed;

   **Total** = `select count(*) from FeedCount  where Pkey='any';`

   **Passed**= `select count(*) from FeedCount  where Pkey='any' and filetype ='abc' and status =true'`
2. Query on just Statuses against given fileType and calculate total
   i.e. Passed + Failed = Total.

   **Passed**= `select count(*) from FeedCount  where Pkey='any' and filetype ='abc' and status =true'`

   **Failed**= `select count(*) from FeedCount  where Pkey='any' and filetype ='abc' and status =false'`

   Point is going over all rows count is efficient or just query with 2nd query to find total?

Answer (score 0):

Imho, there shouldn't be very big difference between two approaches, as you basically read all the data - you have only 2 variants for `status` field, so you're effectively read all data in 2nd case.

The only difference that I could imagine is that in the first case you're doing `select count(*) from FeedCount  where Pkey='any';`, while in 2nd case you're effectively doing `select count(*) from FeedCount  where Pkey='any' AND filetype = 'abc';`, and if you have multiple file types, then your results aren't the same.

Comment: hmmm, so underneath cassandra is going to scan whole table to get the count, what ever is the case?

Comment: I just tried 2nd query it was bit efficient than the 1st case. As cluster key further narrows down the reads. so i feel like 2nd is the good choice ?

Comment: yes, if you partition has multiple file types, yes - it should be more effective.  But in reality, I think that it's faster just because you already did the previous query, and chunks of SSTables are in the file cache, and partition key position is in the key cache... If you're really interested, then more rigorous testing should be done, with tools like DSBench/NoSQLBench...